# Get installed dependency versions at runtime

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to get some information about specific libraries at runtime. So far what I have is a controller that has the following action

```
def getAboutInfo() {
  Resource resource = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/resources/jenkinsBuildInfo')
  def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(resource.getFile().toURI().toURL())
  def sysData = [
    "Application Name": grailsApplication.metadata['app.name'],
    "App Version": grailsApplication.metadata['app.version'],
    "Grails Version": grailsApplication.metadata['app.grails.version'],
    "SVN Revision": config.SVN_REVISION,
    "Build Number": config.BUILD_NUMBER,
    "Build Id": config.BUILD_ID,
    "Java Version": System.getProperty("java.version")
  ]
  def libraryInfo = []

  render([success:true, applicationProperties:sysData,libraryInfo:libraryInfo] as JSON)
}
```

What I'd like to build is a list of information about each library that would look something like this...

```
def libraryInfo = []
['tomcat','joda-time','hibernate','group_id:artifact_id'].each{ name->
  def libInfo = // look up information
  libraryInfo << [
    "Name":name,
    Version:libInfo.version,
    "Build Date":libInfo.build_date,
    "Build Number":libInfo.build_number
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Have you seen [build-info](http://grails.org/plugin/build-info) plugin ?

Comment: I haven't. It looks like this is what I need. Thanks! If you post an answer, then I'll mark it as answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was loading the MANIFEST resource and parsing out the file names from there. This works fine when it's part of a war file and built using with embedded jar files that have the library version in the jar filename.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/gordolio/9236487)

Answer (score 1):

You can use build-info plugin, which will work with your SCM (Git and SVN). It will give you the following information:

> date/time the war file was built
>
> Source Control Revision Number (Git    and Subversion)
>
> application version number
>
> grails version
>
> grails    environment (currently running, not necessarily the
>   environment used  to build the war file)
>
> plugins installed (and which version)

Source: [build-info plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/build-info)

Comment: Actually, looking through the plugin, it doesn't actually get all the info I need. I'd like to get more than just installed plugins. I'd also like to get maven dependencies and their installed versions. This just retrieves the configuration and Jenkins build info (which I already have)